# Does doing pointer arithmetic incur the cost of a divide

Tags: c

I'm working on an embedded processor where the cost of doing a divide is high. When tracking down divide calls in the assembler output I was surprised to see pointer arithmetic generating a call to the divide function.

I can't see how compilers can avoid the divide unless the size of the struct is a power of 2. Anyone know if cleverer compilers like gcc manage to avoid this somehow?

Comment: We need the code, the name of the compiler and the architecture - in that order.

Comment: If you show us the code, we might be able to suggest a way to rewrite it to avoid the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The code fragment was something like this   
    {
   int t1;
   int t2[11];
   int t3;
   int t4;
   int t5[73];
} T;

T array[100];


int findIndex(T *t)
{
   return t - array;
}

Comment: ignore the above - showing my lack of expertise with markdown formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Division by a constant can usually be optimized into a wide multiplication followed by a shift.  This may still be too slow for you, I don't know.  But this only happens for pointer subtraction, which can probably be avoided, depending on how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

On certain processors, when full optimisations are on, compilers can do strength reduction to turn a divide into a multiply. So for instance instead of dividing by 10 they will multiply by 3435973837 and take the upper 32 bits, which is equivalent to multiplying by 0.8, and then divide by 8 using a shift.

Comment: The term ["strength reduction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction) usually refers to a form of loop optimization.  The optimization you describe is valid (I presume; I haven't checked), but I don't think it's "strength reduction" in the usual sense.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The definition from your link: "Strength reduction is a compiler optimization where expensive operations are replaced with equivalent but less expensive operations." This is exactly the case, the loop example in Wikipedia is just, well,  an example.

Comment: @cyco130: I did say "usually".  I don't think I've ever heard the term used to refer to anything other than a loop optimization.  Then again, my experience is not infinite, and you could well be correct.

Comment: @KeithThompson So what do you call replacing `u / 2` with `u >> 1` for example?

Comment: @Neil: Um, optimization?  Or maybe I'm completely wrong and "strength reduction" is the best name for it.